# Using MongoDB in Symfony Monolog Causes Error

Tags: mongodb, symfony, monolog

#### The error I'm getting is like the following:

[image: Screenshot of terminal that shows error in detail]

---

#### Some information that you should know:

1. I'm using Symfony 5
2. I'm able to connect to mongo db using **MongoDB Compass** and in terminal using **mongo** command
3. What packages I have installed are the following:

   - "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.6"
   - "monolog/monolog": "^2.0"
   - "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.5"
4. My configuration file **monolog.yaml** (config/packages/dev/monolog.yaml) is like the following:

```yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        mongo:
            type: mongo
            mongo:
                host: localhost
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had installed mongodb with brew. And I figured out MongoDB\Client class was not recognized. Then I found that we can install mongo driver manually.

1. I followed the steps here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php
2. I've changed my monolog configuration file **monolog.yaml** as

```yaml
monolog:
  handlers:
    mongodb:
      type: mongo
      mongo:
        id: mongolog
```

3. I added MongoDB\Client as service into service configuration file **services.yaml**

```yaml
services:
    ...
    mongolog:
        class: MongoDB\Client
```

And after doing things above, it's worked.